# Batch file to search directory for list of files and copy to single folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a .txt file with a list of files that are on a network drive (M:). I need a batch file to go through that list, search for the files which are in sub-directories of a single folder on that drive, and then copy them to another folder. I have tried quite a few solutions with no luck.

the text file is a list of files and extensions i.e.

```
abc.step
afer.iges
ca76dc7d.sldprt
```

Here's what I tried so far

```
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
cls
set dest=C:\Users\kduquette.000\Desktop\Files 
for /f "TOKENS=*" %%f in (C:Desktop\Files\list.txt) do (
  set i=1
  for /f "tokens=*" %%F IN ('dir M: "%%~f"') Do (
    for %%N in ("%%F") Do (
      set name=%%~NN
      set ext=%%~XN
    )
    copy "%%~F" "%dest%\!name!_!i!!ext!"
    set /A i=!i!+1
  ) 
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: Hey, it would be great if you provided some examples of what you have tried.

Comment: Show some at least one of the solutions you tried please, else it is off topic and the question will be closed.

Comment: ok, so one more thing, what does the text file look like?

Comment: Delete the comment, we do not post code in comments. I updated the question

Comment: ok, thank you. will post an answer now.

Comment: The space in `dir M: "%%~f"` looks suspicious. do you mean `dir /c "M:\%%~f"`?

Comment: also, do you want to do just the root of M: or search subdirectories?

Comment: I believe @Stephan actually meant `dir` **`/B`** `"M:\%%~f"`...

Comment: So are all source files in one directory (`M:\Cads`), or are they spread over multiple sub-directories? Please clarify by [edit]ing your question (do not comment)! Also provide some example content of `list.txt`...

Comment: @aschipfl: yes, correct. I guess it's time for another coffee...

Comment: If your batch file and `list.txt` are both in the directory you're wanting to copy the files to, then you may be able to have only this as your batch file content, `@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In (list.txt)Do Copy /Y "M:\Cads\%%A">Nul 2>&1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can just do a check if file exists and copy it:

```
@echo off
set "dest=C:\Users\kduquette.000\Desktop\Files"
for /f "delims=" %%i in (C:\Desktop\Files\list.txt) do if exist "M:\Cads\%%i" echo copy "M:\Cads\%%i" "%dest%"
```

Note, for now, I added `echo` to the copy string, so you can test the result first. Once happy with the results, remove `echo`

If however you want to search for the files, recursively throughout `M:\` drive then:

```
@echo off
set "dest=C:\Users\kduquette.000\Desktop\Files"
for /f "delims=" %%i in (C:\Desktop\Files\list.txt) do (
    pushd M:\
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s "%%i"') do echo copy "%%~fa" "%dest%"
    popd
)
```